# From time series DB structure to an array/list?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have tried to model my time series data as described in:

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb

Here's a simplified example with two measurement for each hour of the day in a year:

```
{
year: 2042,
id: 42,
dataType: "something",
data : 
    {
    "1" : {
        "1" : [240,210],
        "2" : [230,220],
        "24" : [220,130]
        },
    "365" : {
        "1" : [140,110],
        "2" : [130,120],
        "24" : [120,130]
        }
    }
}
```

With the example above, I like to retrieve the first measurement of each hour as a single array of all the first values in each hour:

```
[240,230,220,140,130,120]
```

I have tried to do it using pymongo/python and loops, but that's too slow and obviously very inefficient. I have also tried to look into aggregation but without any luck.

1. Is it possible to make a query where the data/projection is restructured as the array/list shown above?
2. How could it be done?
3. Do you have any good recommendation for further reading about querying and data manipulation of time series in MongoDB?

Comment: Use `mapReduce`

Comment: Hi Styvane, I'll use Kevin's answer, but I'll take a closer look at mapReduce later this week. TY :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can reconstruct the object by using the aggregation pipeline by using something like the following:

```
    db.messurements.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        year : 1,
        id : 1,
        dataType : 1,
        data: [
            { day: { $literal: 1 }, values : "$data.1"},

            { day: { $literal: 365 }, values : "$data.365"}
        ]}
    }
    ]);
```

Which will result in the following output:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58416371cf34fc678d4f161c"),
        "year" : 2042,
        "id" : 42,
        "dataType" : "something",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "day" : 1,
                        "values" : {
                                "1" : [
                                        240,
                                        210
                                ],
                                "2" : [
                                        230,
                                        220
                                ],
                                "24" : [
                                        220,
                                        130
                                ]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "day" : 365,
                        "values" : {
                                "1" : [
                                        140,
                                        110
                                ],
                                "2" : [
                                        130,
                                        120
                                ],
                                "24" : [
                                        120,
                                        130
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

2) It's not pretty but the following aggregation query would give the expected result:

```
db.messurements.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        year : 1,
        id : 1,
        dataType : 1,
        data: [
            { day: { $literal: 1 }, values : "$data.1"},
            { day: { $literal: 365 }, values : "$data.365"}
    ]}},
    {$unwind: "$data"},
    {$project: {
        year : 1,
        id : 1,
        dataType : 1,
        data: [
            { day: "$data.day", hour: { $literal: 1 }, values : "$data.values.1"},
            { day: "$data.day", hour: { $literal: 2 }, values : "$data.values.2"},
            { day: "$data.day", hour: { $literal: 24 }, values : "$data.values.24"}
    ]}},
    {$unwind: "$data"},
    {$project: {
        year : 1,
        day: "$data.day",
        hour: "$data.hour",
        id : 1,
        dataType : 1,
        values: "$data.values"
    }},
    {$unwind: "$values"},
    {$group: {
        _id: {
            year: "$year",
            day :"$day",
            hour: "$hour"},
        data: {$first: "$values"}
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: "",
        data: { $push : "$data" }
    }}
]);
```

Will output:

```
{ "_id" : "", "data" : [ 120, 130, 140, 220, 230, 240 ] }
```

3)
I find the mongodb site very resourceful for what you can do with data manipulation, see - https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/

Comment: HI Kevin, thank you very much for the very detailed answers! It is highly appreciated! :-)